# Is this Florida poison-Ivy?

Tags: poison-ivy

[image: poison ivy plant]Trying to determine if this poison ivy. Plant is located in the state of Florida.

Answer (score 2):

No. I have seen some minor variation in appearance depending on growing condition, but not geographic location. Poison ivy 20 feet up a tree in Louisiana swamp may be bigger than some in limited water location in Illinois , but it is caused by local conditions. Poison Ivy has triple leaves with large scallops or notches, not symmetrical, on the margin.

Comment: I agree - definitely not poison ivy.